# jQuery - Set class on a parent element

Tags: jquery

Considering the following HTML:

```
<div class="icongroup inline">
  <a href="http://www.google.be">
    <div class="bigicon icon relative inline center disabled">
      <img id="delete" src="Resources/Icons/Delete.png" alt="Delete">
      <div class="iconlegend">Delete</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Now, I have a jQuery selector that takes the delete element:

```
var element = $("#delete");
```

And now I want to disable the anchor element that's somewhere above the element.

Current, I do use this code:

```
$(element).parent().parent().on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
})
```

That's working without an issue, but I was just wondering if there is a more cleaner solution to do this. Thus, not using the parent().parent()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
element.closest('a').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

It's worth noting that `element` is already a jQuery element, so you can chain jQuery methods to it directly, rather than re-wrapping with jQuery.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 1):

Yep:

```
element.closest("a").on("click", function() {
```

Comment: You get a +1 for answering 1 minute earlier ^.^